# c++ get indices of duplicating rows in 2D array

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array, stl

The task is following: find indices of duplicating rows of 2D array. Rows considered to be  duplicated if 2nd and 4th elements of one row are equal to 2nd and 4th elements of another row.The simplest way to do it is something like that:

```
std::unordered_set<int> result;
for (int i = 0; i < rows_count; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < rows_count; ++j)
    {
        if (arr[i][2] == arr[j][2] && arr[i][4] == arr[j][4])
        {
            result.push_back(j);
        }
    }
}
```

But if `rows_count` is very large this algorithm is too slow. So my question is there any way to get needed indices using some data structures (from stl or other) with only single loop (without nested loop)?

Comment: Sure. You seem to know containers. Shouldn't this be obvious: an unordered map of 2nd+4th value tuples (with a suitable hash and equality operator), to row indexes?

Comment: your approach is O(N*N) when you sort the rows it can be done in O(N logN)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik if, let's say, 1st, 3rd and 6th rows are duplicates, which index will be stored in the map? I need to get all duplicated indices (e.g. 3 and 6), so I didn't find a way to solve the problem with map.
I need to get indices in original array, so sorting is not my case

Comment: What do you mean "didn't find a way to solve the problem with map"??? Maps can store anything. If you want the map to store the list of all duplicate row indexes, can't you simply create a map that does that? And if that's what you want to do, your current code, using the set, will not work and it will miss some duplicates, by the way. What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook this practice problem is from, or what was the topic of the class that this homework assignment is from? What you're asking about should've be explained already, in book/class, before assigning this problem.

Comment: Do you mean map with tuple as a key and vector of integers as a value in which indices will be stored? This isn't homework or exercise from a book. This is real task. The task is remove all duplicates from 2D grid (like excel's remove duplicates function from data tab). So I get range of rows (including columns) and vector of columns numbers to compare (to find duplicates).

Comment: Of course, that's the direct, taking-the-bull-by-the-horns approach.

Comment: What you need is a map from `std:tuple<T, T>` (where `T` is the array element type) to `std::set<size_t>` (or `std::unordered_set<size_t>`, depending on whether and when sorting matters, how you want to report the results etc.). Keys in the map will be pairs of 2. and 4. row elements. Values in the map will be sets of indices of rows that share the same 2. and 4. elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of the properties of a `std::unordered_set.

A small helper class will further ease up things.

So, we can store in a class the 2nd and 4th value and use a comparision function to detect duplicates.

The [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) has, besides the data type, 2 additional template parameters.

1. A functor for equality and
2. a functor for calculating a hash function.

So we will add 2 functions to our class an make it a functor for both parameters at the same time. In the below code you will see:

```
std::unordered_set<Dupl, Dupl, Dupl> dupl{};
```

So, we use our class additionally as 2 functors.

The rest of the functionality will be done by the `std::unordered_set`

Please see below one of many potential solutions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

struct Dupl {
    Dupl() {}
    Dupl(const size_t row, const std::vector<int>& data) : index(row), firstValue(data[2]), secondValue(data[4]){};
    
    size_t index{};
    int firstValue{};
    int secondValue{};

    // Hash function
    std::size_t operator()(const Dupl& d) const noexcept {
        return d.firstValue + (d.secondValue << 8) + (d.index << 16);
    }
    // Comparison
    bool operator()(const Dupl& lhs, const Dupl& rhs) const {
        return  (lhs.firstValue == rhs.firstValue) and (lhs.secondValue == rhs.secondValue);
    }
};

std::vector<std::vector<int>> data{
    {1,   2,   3,  4,   5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10},              // Index 0
    {2,   3,   4,  5,   6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11},              // Index 1
    {3,   4,  42,  6,  42,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12},              // Index 2   ***
    {4,   5,   6,  7,   8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13},              // Index 3
    {5,   6,  42,  8,  42,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14},              // Index 4   ***
    {6,   7,   8,  9,  10,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15},              // Index 5
    {7,   8,   9, 10,  11,  12, 13, 14, 15, 16},              // Index 6
    {8,   9,  10, 11,  12,  13, 14, 15, 16, 17},              // Index 7
    {9,  10,  42, 12,  42,  14, 15, 16, 17, 18},              // Index 8   ***
    {10, 11,  12, 13,  14,  15, 16, 17, 18, 19},              // Index 9

};

int main() {

    std::unordered_set<Dupl, Dupl, Dupl> dupl{};

    // Find the unique rows
    for (size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
        dupl.insert({i, data[i]});

    // Show some debug output
    for (const Dupl& d : dupl) {
        std::cout << "\nIndex:\t " << d.index << "\t\tData: ";
        for (const int i : data[d.index]) std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I've implemented solution based on your answer